# how to not go to google play when you click the request

Tags: android, facebook, request, handle

Say a friend has sent a request to you and you accept the request, then you are going to be moved to *google play* even though you already have the app installed in your device.

1. How can you control it not to go to the google play?
2. How do you know that there is a request for the user, just inside the app. Not seeing the
   Facebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Play has been configured as the default application to manage these requests; go to `Settings > Apps > Google Play Store` and tap "Clear Defaults." The next time you accept a request, Android should ask you what is the app to use to complete the action.